# Limiting a Group of Select Boxes to Allow Only One to be a Certain Value

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'd like to make a set of select boxes function in a way that only one can be "yes".  So, if the user selects "yes", all others are set to "no".

I thought I had code that worked.  Unfortunately, I have discovered that the code does not work in Firefox if the user is using the keyboard exclusively for navigation.  It works fine if the user uses a mouse to change a field.  Just to clarify, 0 is the value for "No".

Here is the function:

```
function f_one(cls)
{
    $('.'+cls).filter('select').not('.'+cls+':focus').val('0');
}
```

It is called in the onchange event of the group of select boxes that resemble the following:

```
<select name="crrnt" id="crrnt" class="cAgo" onchange="f_one('cAgo')">
```

I also tried to have the onkeyup event mimic the onchange event.  It did not work either. It actually set field back to 0 when focus was lost.

So, any suggestions on patching the code or a replacement would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/s3QEK/2/

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  if(this.value === 'yes'){
    $('select[data-group="'+$(this).data('group')+'"]:not([name="'+this.name+'"])').filter(function(){
      return this.value === 'yes';
    }).val('no');
  }
});
```

Comment: This works fine for a form with only one group of selects.  Unfortunately, the page has multiple groups of selects.  The code did work for just one group, even with keyboard navigation.

Comment: @user1579354 I updated the link. Check out the update, for each set of select boxes change the `data-group=""`.